# Fractional Josephson effect explained

Tags: superconductivity, majorana-fermions

I am confused by the [fractional Josephson effect](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=fractional+Josephson+effect). I still don't know if there has to be parity conservation or not. Is the fractional Josepshon effect always connected to fermion parity anomaly ([Beenakker et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5412))? What happens in long and short junction limit?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment: I think that the most lucid statement about this point is still the original discussion by Kitaev: http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440 (see especially section 4) that people should read and read and read and read and read again ... It helps :-)

Comment: The ground state of the system changes parity while advancing the phsse $\phi$ by $2\pi$. I think that this is the fermion parity anomaly. But, I still don't understand why there has to be a topological phase transistion - there are some low energy hamiltonian arguments (Kane, Fu 2009) but all the talk is about **tunelling** mechanism. What about normal metal or geometrical constriction instead of insulator?

Comment: As far as the fractional Josephson effect due to topological superconductivity goes, the answer is yes -- you need parity conservation (of the entire junction) to see the full $4\pi$ periodicity. If electrons are allowed to tunnel into the junction, for example from external leads, the system will always jump to the ground state, restoring a $2\pi$ periodicity as a function of the phase. Hope this helps; I will try to write a full answer in the coming days.